# Use PS0 and PS1 to display execution time of each bash command

Tags: bash, performance, shell, ps1

It seems that by executing code in PS0 and PS1 variables (which are eval'ed before and after a prompt command is run, as I understand) it should be possible to record time of each running command and display it in the prompt. Something like that:

```
user@machine ~/tmp
$ sleep 1

user@machine ~/tmp 1.01s
$
```

However, I quickly got stuck with recording time in PS0, since something like this doesn't work:

```
PS0='$(START=$(date +%s.%N))'
```

As I understand, `START` assignment happens in a sub-shell, so it is not visible in the outer shell. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for a solution to a different problem and came upon this question, and decided that sounds like a cool feature to have. Using [@Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff)'s excellent answer as a base in addition to the solutions I developed for my other problem, I came up with a more elegant and full featured solution.

First, I created a few functions that read/write the time to/from memory. Writing to the shared memory folder prevents disk access and does not persist on reboot if the files are not cleaned for some reason

```
function roundseconds (){
  # rounds a number to 3 decimal places
  echo m=$1";h=0.5;scale=4;t=1000;if(m<0) h=-0.5;a=m*t+h;scale=3;a/t;" | bc
}

function bash_getstarttime (){
  # places the epoch time in ns into shared memory
  date +%s.%N >"/dev/shm/${USER}.bashtime.${1}"
}

function bash_getstoptime (){
  # reads stored epoch time and subtracts from current
  local endtime=$(date +%s.%N)
  local starttime=$(cat /dev/shm/${USER}.bashtime.${1})
  roundseconds $(echo $(eval echo "$endtime - $starttime") | bc)
}
```

The input to the bash_ functions is the bash PID

Those functions and the following are added to the ~/.bashrc file

```
ROOTPID=$BASHPID
bash_getstarttime $ROOTPID
```

These create the initial time value and store the bash PID as a different variable that can be passed to a function. Then you add the functions to PS0 and PS1

```
PS0='$(bash_getstarttime $ROOTPID) etc..'
PS1='\[\033[36m\] Execution time $(bash_getstoptime $ROOTPID)s\n'
PS1="$PS1"'and your normal PS1 here'
```

Now it will generate the time in PS0 prior to processing terminal input, and generate the time again in PS1 after processing terminal input, then calculate the difference and add to PS1. And finally, this code cleans up the stored time when the terminal exits:

```
function runonexit (){
  rm /dev/shm/${USER}.bashtime.${ROOTPID}
}

trap runonexit EXIT
```

Putting it all together, plus some additional code being tested, and it looks like this:

[image: Terminal Output]

The important parts are the execution time in ms, and the user.bashtime files for all active terminal PIDs stored in shared memory. The PID is also shown right after the terminal input, as I added display of it to PS0, and you can see the bashtime files added and removed.

```
PS0='$(bash_getstarttime $ROOTPID) $ROOTPID experiments \[\033[00m\]\n'
```

Answer (score 10):

As [@tc said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415835/5411817), using arithmetic expansion allows you to assign variables during the expansion of `PS0` and `PS1`. Newer bash versions also allow `PS*` style expansion so you don't even need a subshell to get the current time. With bash 4.4:

```
# PS0 extracts a substring of length 0 from PS1; as a side-effect it causes
# the current time as epoch seconds to PS0time (no visible output in this case)
PS0='\[${PS1:$((PS0time=\D{%s}, PS1calc=1, 0)):0}\]'
# PS1 uses the same trick to calculate the time elapsed since PS0 was output.
# It also expands the previous command's exit status ($?), the current time
# and directory ($PWD rather than \w, which shortens your home directory path
# prefix to "~") on the next line, and finally the actual prompt: 'user@host> '
PS1='\nSeconds: $((PS1calc ? \D{%s}-$PS0time : 0)) Status: $?\n\D{%T} ${PWD:PS1calc=0}\n\u@\h> '
```

(The `%N` date directive does not seem to be implemented as part of `\D{...}` expansion with bash 4.4. This is a pity since we only have a resolution in single second units.)

Since `PS0` is only evaluated and printed if there is a command to execute, the `PS1calc` flag is set to `1` to do the time difference (following the command) in `PS1` expansion or not (`PS1calc` being `0` means `PS0` was not previously expanded and so didn't re-evaluate `PS1time`). `PS1` then resets `PS1calc` to `0`. In this way an empty line (just hitting return) doesn't accumulate seconds between return key presses.

One nice thing about this method is that there is no output when you have `set -x` active. No subshells or temporary files in sight: everything is done within the bash process itself.

Answer (score 4):

Arithmetic expansion runs in the current process and can assign to variables. It also produces output, which you can consume with something like `\e[$((...,0))m` (to output `\e[0m`) or `${t:0:$((...,0))}` (to output nothing, which is presumably better). 64-bit integer support in Bash supports will count POSIX nanoseconds until the year 2262.

```
$ PS0='${t:0:$((t=$(date +%s%N),0))}'
$ PS1='$((( t )) && printf %d.%09ds $((t=$(date +%s%N)-t,t/1000000000)) $((t%1000000000)))${t:0:$((t=0))}\n$ '
0.053282161s
$ sleep 1
1.064178281s
$ 

$
```

PS0 is not evaluated for empty commands, which leaves a blank line (I'm not sure if you can conditionally print the \n without breaking things). You can work around that by switching to PROMPT_COMMAND instead (which also saves a fork):

```
$ PS0='${t:0:$((t=$(date +%s%N),0))}'
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='(( t )) && printf %d.%09ds\\n $((t=$(date +%s%N)-t,t/1000000000)) $((t%1000000000)); t=0'
0.041584565s
$ sleep 1
1.077152833s
$ 
$
```

That said, if you do not require sub-second precision, I would suggest using `$SECONDS` instead (which is also more likely to return a sensible answer if something sets the time).

Answer (score 3):

I took this as puzzle and want to show the result of my puzzling:

First I fiddled with time measurement. The `date +%s.%N` (which I didn't realize before) was where I started from. Unfortunately, it seems that `bash`s arithmetic evaluation seems not to support floating points. Thus, I chosed something else:

```
$ START=$(date +%s.%N)

$ awk 'BEGIN { printf("%fs", '$(date +%s.%N)' - '$START') }' /dev/null
8.059526s

$
```

This is sufficient to compute the time difference.

Next, I confirmed what you already described: sub-shell invocation prevents usage of shell variables. Thus, I thought about where else I could store the start time which is global for sub-shells but local enough to be used in multiple interactive shells concurrently. My solution are temp. files (in `/tmp`). To provide a unique name I came up with this pattern: `/tmp/$USER.START.$BASHPID`.

```
$ date +%s.%N >/tmp/$USER.START.$BASHPID ; \
> awk 'BEGIN { printf("%fs", '$(date +%s.%N)' - '$(cat /tmp/$USER.START.$BASHPID)') }' /dev/null
cat: /tmp/ds32737.START.11756: No such file or directory
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { printf("%fs", 1491297723.111219300 - ) }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                              ^ syntax error

$
```

Damn! Again I'm trapped in the sub-shell issue. To come around this, I defined another variable:

```
$ INTERACTIVE_BASHPID=$BASHPID

$ date +%s.%N >/tmp/$USER.START.$INTERACTIVE_BASHPID ; \
> awk 'BEGIN { printf("%fs", '$(date +%s.%N)' - '$(cat /tmp/$USER.START.$INTERACTIVE_BASHPID)') }' /dev/null
0.075319s

$
```

Next step: fiddle this together with `PS0` and `PS1`. In a similar puzzle ([SO: How to change bash prompt color based on exit code of last command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015463/how-to-change-bash-prompt-color-based-on-exit-code-of-last-command/43015676#43015676)), I already mastered the "quoting hell". Thus, I should be able to do it again:

```
$ PS0='$(date +%s.%N >"/tmp/${USER}.START.${INTERACTIVE_BASHPID}")'

$ PS1='$(awk "BEGIN { printf(\"%fs\", "$(date +%s.%N)" - "$(cat /tmp/$USER.START.$INTERACTIVE_BASHPID)") }" /dev/null)'"$PS1"
0.118550s
$
```

Ahh. It starts to work. Thus, there is only one issue - to find the right start-up script for the initialization of `INTERACTIVE_BASHPID`. I found `~/.bashrc` which seems to be the right one for this, and which I already used in the past for some other personal customizations.

So, putting it all together - these are the lines I added to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# command duration puzzle
INTERACTIVE_BASHPID=$BASHPID
date +%s.%N >"/tmp/${USER}.START.${INTERACTIVE_BASHPID}"
PS0='$(date +%s.%N >"/tmp/${USER}.START.${INTERACTIVE_BASHPID}")'
PS1='$(awk "BEGIN { printf(\"%fs\", "$(date +%s.%N)" - "$(cat /tmp/$USER.START.$INTERACTIVE_BASHPID)") }" /dev/null)'"$PS1"
```

The 3rd line (the `date` command) has been added to solve another issue. Comment it out and start a new interactive bash to find out why.

A snapshot of my cygwin xterm with bash where I added the above lines to `./~bashrc`:
[image: Snapshot of my cygwin xterm with the "tuned" bash prompt]

Notes:

1. I consider this rather as solution to a puzzle than a "serious productive" solution. I'm sure that this kind of time measurement consumes itself a lot of time. The `time` command might provide a better solution: [SE: How to get execution time of a script effectively?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively). However, this was a nice lecture for practicing the bash...
2. Don't forget that this code pollutes your `/tmp` directory with a growing number of small files. Either clean-up the `/tmp` from time to time or add the appropriate commands for clean-up (e.g. to `~/.bash_logout`).

Answer (score 1):

As correctly stated in the question, `PS0` runs inside a sub-shell which makes it unusable for this purpose of setting the start time.

Instead, one can use the `history` command with epoch seconds `%s` and the built-in variable `$EPOCHSECONDS` to calculate when the command finished by leveraging only `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

```
# Save start time before executing command (does not work due to PS0 sub-shell)
# preexec() {
#   STARTTIME=$EPOCHSECONDS
# }
# PS0=preexec

# Save end time, without duplicating commands when pressing Enter on an empty line
precmd() {
    local st=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT='%s ' history 1 | awk '{print $2}');
    if [[ -z "$STARTTIME" || (-n "$STARTTIME" && "$STARTTIME" -ne "$st") ]]; then
        ENDTIME=$EPOCHSECONDS
        STARTTIME=$st
    else
        ENDTIME=0
    fi
}

__timeit() {
    precmd;
    if ((ENDTIME - STARTTIME >= 0)); then
        printf 'Command took %d seconds.\n' "$((ENDTIME - STARTTIME))";
    fi

    # Do not forget your:
    #     - OSC 0 (set title)
    #     - OSC 777 (notification in gnome-terminal, urxvt; note, this one has preexec and precmd as OSC 777 features)
    #     - OSC 99 (notification in kitty)
    #     - OSC 7 (set url) - out of scope for this question
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=__timeit
```

Note: If you have `ignoredups` in your `$HISTCONTROL`, then this will not report back for a command that is re-run.

Answer (score 1):

Following @SherylHohman use of variables in PS0 I've come with this complete script. I've seen you don't need a `PS0Time` flag as `PS0Calc` doesn't exists on empty prompts so `_elapsed` funct just exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

# string preceding ms, use color code or ascii
_ELAPTXT=$'\E[1;33m \uf135 '

# extract time
_printtime () {
    local _var=${EPOCHREALTIME/,/};
    echo ${_var%???}
}

# get diff time, print it and end color codings if any
_elapsed () {
    [[ -v "${1}" ]] || ( local _VAR=$(_printtime);
    local _ELAPSED=$(( ${_VAR} - ${1} ));
    echo "${_ELAPTXT}$(_formatms ${_ELAPSED})"$'\n\e[0m' )
}

# format _elapsed with simple string substitution
_formatms () {
    local _n=$((${1})) && case ${_n} in
        ? | ?? | ???)
            echo $_n"ms"
        ;;
        ????)
            echo ${_n:0:1}${_n:0,-3}"ms"
        ;;
        ?????)
            echo ${_n:0:2}","${_n:0,-3}"s"
        ;;
        ??????)
            printf $((${_n:0:3}/60))m+$((${_n:0:3}%60)),${_n:0,-3}"s"
        ;;
        ???????)
            printf $((${_n:0:4}/60))m$((${_n:0:4}%60))s${_n:0,-3}"ms"
        ;;
        *)
            printf "too much!"
        ;;
    esac
}

# prompts
PS0='${PS1:(PS0time=$(_printtime)):0}'
PS1='$(_elapsed $PS0time)${PS0:(PS0time=0):0}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

[img of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFxHp.png)

Save it as _prompt and source it to try:
`source _prompt`

Change text, ascii codes and colors in _ELAPTXT
`_ELAPTXT='\e[33m Elapsed time: '`