# How to calculate execute time after all of commands automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell

After a command in bash i want the execution time for that command redirect to file but not use `time` before every command.
I try trap but I can't redirect trap output to file. I also try PROMPT_COMMAND; but this *environment variable* run after user command not before it.
What I mean:

```
$ nano Foo.txt
```

and in the log file or output (generally stdout):

> nano Foo.txt: 14:38

(for instance)

I try use PS0 and PS1 but PS0 for bash version least 4.4 and my bash in workplace lower

Comment: Have you looked into [Use PS0 and PS1 to display execution time of each bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43201274/3266847)?