# Display the exit code of previous command only when it's non-zero, without using commands?

Tags: bash, ps1, parameter-expansion

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772796/5958455) implementing command execution time display with only substitutions, I'm trying to rewrite my exit code display with the same feature - it should produce no extra output even under `set -x`.

This is my current `.bashrc`:

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND() {
  local e=$?
  PROMPT_ECODE=""
  (( e )) && PROMPT_ECODE="$e|"
  return $e
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=PROMPT_COMMAND
PS1='${PROMPT_ECODE}'"$PS1"
```

The current display result is exactly what I need: If `$?` is non-zero, show it before the usual PS1, with a vertical bar in between. If `$?` is zero, do nothing and display PS1.

This implementation produces some 4 extra lines for every PS1 printed if `set -x`. This is annoying and I'd like to avoid it.

---

**Y problem:** I know I can append a vertical bar to a non-zero `$?` with `${?:+$?|}`, but I'm stuck at expanding a zero `$?` to nothing (empty string). I can't find a way to assign an empty string to an existing non-empty variable in the process of Parameter Expansion or Arithmetic Expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can append a vertical bar to a non-zero $? with ${?:+$?|}, but I'm stuck at expanding a zero $? to nothing (empty string). I can't find a way to assign an empty string to an existing non-empty variable in the process of Parameter Expansion or Arithmetic Expansion.

You can do this with the help of a small utility array:

```
_only_1=([1]=1)
```

Then `_only_1[1]` has a defined value, but `_only_1[0]` does not, thus
`${_only_1[1]:+foo}` evaluates to `foo`, but `${_only_1[0]:+foo}` evaluates to nothing.  The idea would be that this array is defined once, perhaps in your `.bash_profile`, not every time your prompt is computed.

We can combine that with arithmetic evaluation to squash all non-zero exit statuses to 1: `((\!\!$?))`.  The `\!` is the logical negation operator, escaped to avoid triggering history expansion.

Put together, we have something like this:

```
${_only_1[((\!\!$?))]:+$?|}
```

... which expands to nothing when $? is 0, and to the same thing as "$?|" when $? is nonzero.
Demo:

```
_only_1=([1]=1)
set -x
echo "${_only_1[((\!\!$?))]:+$?|}"
(exit 3)
echo "${_only_1[((\!\!$?))]:+$?|}"
```

output:

```
+ echo ''

+ exit 3
+ echo '3|'
3|
```

That's a bit cluttered up with the `exit` and `echo` commands, but those should be attributed to the demo framework.  The key thing to observe is thet there is no trace output for the expansions that produce alternatively nothing or `3|`.

Note that if ever that `_only_1` support array happens to be unset, which could happen for a variety of reasons, then you will lose the exit-code augmentation of your prompt, but you should not otherwise be adversely affected.  Similarly, if `_only_1[0]` gets defined to a non-null value, then you will start getting prompt augmentation for exit status 0, too, but there should be no other adverse effect.

**Update:**

I realized after the fact that I made this slightly more complicated than needed.  I could have instead relied on an array with only index 0 defined, and used single-negation instead of double:

```
_only_0=(0)

# ...

(exit 3)
echo "${_only_0[((\!$?))]:+$?|}"
```

Comment: Never thought arrays could be used that way. You're so smart to come up with this answer.

Comment: Maybe my Bash is bugged, but it wouldn't recognize escaped exclamation marks: `-bash: ((\!\!3)): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\!\!3))")`

Comment: Worked around History Expansion by leaving a space after *each* exclamation mark, instead of trying to escape it with a backslash (which doesn't work).

Comment: @iBug, I can imagine there being differences in that area between different Bash versions.  I worked up the example on version 4.3.48, which is a bit old these days.  I'm glad you found a workaround.

Comment: `_only_0` isn't even needed: Any existing string variable could be used instead, and they'll behave identically as an array variable with only `[0]` set.

Comment: `man bash`: *Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0. Any reference to a variable using a valid subscript is legal, and bash will create an array if necessary.*.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by declaring an error function to control return code  demo purposes.

```bash
err(){ return $1;}
```

Then to print nothing when `$? = 0`, just delete the whole message string when it starts with `0 |`

```bash
for i in 0 1 2 3
do
  err $i # RC generator
  msg="$? | "
  echo "${msg#0 | }" # Erase message if it starts with a 0 | 
done
```

That's only one extra line of debug when assigning `$msg`.

Comment: Nice try. But 1 extra debug line is what I can already achieve before asking this question, and my goal is zero. +1 anyways.